# Method called by Pointer to Vector can't modify object

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I've been searching for a similar problem on the web but I could not find anything helpful, here's the Problem:

When `DeleteConnectedEdges` calls `Method1` on `Element 1` of the `Vector Edges` it seems `Method1` can't modify data but there's no error saying so.

How can I make this work? Thank you very much.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
std::vector<GenericEdgeClass> Edges;
...
}

class GenericNodeClass {
private:
    std::vector<GenericEdgeClass> *Edges;
public:
    GenericNodeClass(
        std::vector<GenericEdgeClass> *EdgesPtr,
        Point3DClass position,
        ID_TYPE new_ID);
    virtual ~GenericNodeClass();
    ID_TYPE ID;
    void DeleteConnectedEdges() {
             ((GenericEdgeClass)(*Edges)[1]).Method1();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((GenericEdgeClass)(*Edges)[1]).Method1();
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What is that cast doing there? That causes the function to be called on a temporary copy of the object in `Edges`, not the object itself, which is why you don't see whatever modification it's supposed to make. The fix is simply to get rid of it:

```
(*Edges)[1].Method1();
```

Comment: Works! Thank you! (I thought you had to cast when using pointers to vectors but obviously I was very wrong)